# The following statement will find all the customers who have no order or who have order?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, null, not-exists

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            orders
        WHERE
            orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
    )
ORDER BY
    name;
```

and if you can tell me how to use not exists and select null?

Answer (score 0):

The `not exists` condition ensures that there is no record in the `orders` table for the corresponding `customer_id`.

This query gives you all customers that have no order.

It does not really matter what the subquery under the `not exists` condition returns: the point of `not exists` is to check whether the subquery returns *something*. A often-met convention is to use `select 1`, but it may actually be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks okay.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM orders o
                  WHERE o.customer_id = c.customer_id
                 )
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Notes:

- This is equivalent to your query.
- This uses table aliases, which I recommend.
- I am just not a fan of `SELECT NULL`.  `NULL` usually means "missing" or "unknown".  Plus `SELECT 1` is easier to type.  However, `EXISTS` is checking for the existence of *rows* so the value doesn't matter.